# Maven - CDI error when deploying on Glassfish Web Profile

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, cdi

I'm new to maven.

When trying to deploy WAR app on Glassfish Server 3.1.2.2 **Web Profile** build with maven 3.0.4 on Linux the following error occur: "**org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [...]**".

There is nothing wrong with CDI on the classes that this error acuses. The proof is: the **same build** works on Glassfish Server 3.1.2.2 **Full Profile**. The project has **beans.xml** on main/webapp/WEB-INF.

An interesting detail is, when i remove the "**provided**" scope from the dependencies, the error disappear and the deploy works fine.

The generated WAR with default scope "compile" give me a **24MB** file. The generated WAR with "provided" scope give me a **11MB** file.

Please correct me if i'm wrong, but i think there is no need to put libs inside war that will be provided by the application server. What am i missing here?

The application uses JSF 2.1, EJB 3.1, CDI 1.0, JPA 2.0 and JTA specifications.

So here's my pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>alfabr</groupId>
    <artifactId>AlfaBR</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>AlfaBR Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>maven.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-b33</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <verbose />
                    <bootclasspath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>       
       </plugins>
    <finalName>AlfaBR</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: And the offending class code - you're probably injecting something that's not part of the Java EE Web Profile. Also, it is highly unlikely that this has anything to do with maven.

Comment: You are right. Thank you, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@rdcrng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1789351/rdcrng) is right. This has nothing to do with maven.

We are moving the application from Glassfish Full Profile to Web Profile and starting to use maven.

So i found a **JAX-WS 2.2** annotation in one of the injected dependencies. JAX-WS is not included in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 Web Profile as says [here](http://glassfish.java.net/webprofileORfullplatform31x.html).

I remove it and the build was deployed successfully.